# Defining the proximity between sentences

Tags: machine-learning, references, text-mining, kernel-trick, metric

What are the common ways to define proximity between two sentences ? I did various tries, including:

- [Jaccard Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)
- [Cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)
- [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

either using the counts for the Jaccard and Cosine "metrics" or the TFIDF for the cosine similarity. They performed relatively well.

Some (string specific) kernels can be adapted as well:

- [The subsequence kernel](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume2/lodhi02a/lodhi02a.pdf)
- [The spectrum kernel](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/teatimetalks/kernelclub04/spectrum.pdf)

And general kernels can be applied (Polynomial, Gaussian, Information diffusion...)

Am I missing any possible similarity measure ? 
Is any state-of-art in defining metrics over texts available ?

Comment: "Diffusion Kernels on Statistical Manifolds" by Lafferty and Lebanon develops a kernel function which the authors claim is more powerful than linear and RBF kernels. Note that all the methods you've outlined are just string similarity or bag-of-words methods. So you could add some value by looking into part-of-speech tagging methods and n-grams.

Comment: @user777 Thank you! I forgot to mention that I tried ID-kernel it as well. It gave better results than a simple cosine, actually. Do you have more references regarding "part of speech tagging?"

Comment: You might start here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging